# Can I use the flash.net.NetConnection over https

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, tomcat, https

Is it possible to use the flash.net.NetConnection object to connect to my Flash remoting enabled web application over HTTPS within Tomcat or any other servlet container?

I am using the SpiceFactory cinnamon project for amf remoting and have searched for examples of using HTTPS but see only the reference to a proxy type in the NetConnection object.

If someone could provide a reference or example that would be awesome. Or if it is not possible using the flash.net.NetConnection object are there any recommendations of how to configure HTTPS for the spicefactory cinnamon library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the creator Jens Halm, it should just work out of the box.
http://www.spicefactory.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=407

Comment: Touche, maybe I will give this a bit more effort.

Comment: So... this does in fact work out of the box. I had some stupid problems in my keystore. But after fixing this it worked no problem. 

On another note... BlazeDS requires configuration changes so +1 Pimento

Answer (score 0):

flex https works fine , if you use self signed certificate end user needs to add the public key manually to the trusted store, by directly connecting to the site using https://...
and accept the certificate.

second way is run the connection over http and do the encryption / description manually using 
as3crypto  - flex  http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/ and php openssl